# Trying to copy a varying number of cells into a fixed number of rows - copy fails when number of cells copied exceeds the last row number

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you experienced programmers for being willing to help out. I have no formal training so try not to laugh too hard when reading my code. This is also the first time I've attempted to seek outside help so I'm sincerely hoping I don't violate any rules.

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. The macro I wrote is attempting to copy a varying number of cell values (all text) (e.g. one sheet may have 3 items to copy, another may have ten) into a column that has a fixed number of 30 rows. The problem I'm having is trying to figure out on the fly how to keep track of when the data being copied exceeds the available space remaining in which to paste. After the first 30 cells have been copied, I have a Select Case statement that offsets to the next column of 30 rows, etc. and the macro continues until to the last sheet that has data has been copied.

I'm copying the code that I've written - I hope this window is the correct spot.

Thanks, JA

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateDraw()
        ' This code will populate the Roll Call sheet
        ' 1. Go to Running Order sheet to get the sheet order
        ' 2. For each sheet determine the number entered in each stake
        ' 3. Copy the populated registration number from column D to the Roll Call sheet.
        ' 4. After 30 cells have been copied switch the column on the Roll Call sheet.
        ' 5. After 60 cells have been copied switch the column on the Roll Call sheet.
        ' 6. After 90 cells have been copied switch the column on the Roll Call sheet.

    Dim a, b, c, d, e, x As Integer
    Dim y As String

    a = 1 'Offset for pasting to Roll Call Sheet
    b = 0 'Offset for number of Open stake entries
    c = 0 'Offset for number of Special stake entries
    d = 0 'Offset for number of Veteran stake entries
    e = 0 'Offset for Column shift based on number of entries copied
    x = 0 'Loop counter - goes to 21
    y = "" 'Sheet to select based on loop counter

    Do Until x = 21
        Select Case a
            Case 1 To 30: e = 0 And a = 1
            Case 31 To 60: e = 5 And a = 1
            Case 61 To 90: e = -10 And a = 34
            Case 91 To 120: e = -5 And a = 34
            Case 121 To 150: e = 0 And a = 34
            Case 151 To 180: e = 5 And a = 34
        Case Else:
            MsgBox "Case Not Found"
        End Select


    Sheets("Running Order").Select

    With ActiveSheet
        y = .Range("A2").Offset(x, 0).Value
    End With
    If y = "RR(A)" Or y = "RR(B)" Then
        Sheets(y).Select
        'GoTo Copy_RR
    ElseIf y = "WH(A)" Or y = "WH(B)" Then
        Sheets(y).Select
        GoTo Copy_Wh
    Else:
        Sheets(y).Select
        GoTo Copy_Regular
    End If
Copy_Regular:
             'Select Copy data for Open Stake

            With ActiveSheet
                If .Range("L4") = 0 Then
                    'No entries on this sheet
                    b = 0
                ElseIf .Range("L4") = 1 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Copy
                    b = 1
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                ElseIf .Range("L4") > 1 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D9", ActiveSheet.Range("D9").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D9:D20"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                End If

                'Select Copy data for Specials
                Sheets(y).Select
                If .Range("L27") = 0 Then
                a = a
                ElseIf .Range("L27") = 1 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D32").Copy
                    c = 1
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                ElseIf .Range("L27") > 1 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D32", ActiveSheet.Range("D32").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D32:D43"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                Else:
                a = a
                End If

                'Select Copy data for Veterans
                Sheets(y).Select
                If .Range("L50") = 0 Then
                a = a
                ElseIf .Range("L50") = 1 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D55").Copy
                    d = 1
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + d
                ElseIf .Range("L50") > 1 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D55", ActiveSheet.Range("D55").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    d = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D55:D66"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + d
                Else:
                a = a
                End If
            End With
            GoTo End_Loop

Copy_RR:
             'Select Copy data for Open Stake
            Sheets(y).Select
            With ActiveSheet
                If .Range("L4") = 0 Then
                    'No entries in Open
                    b = 0
                ElseIf .Range("L4") > 0 And .Range("L4") <= 12 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D9", ActiveSheet.Range("D9").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D9:D20"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                            Sheets(y).Select
                ElseIf .Range("L4") > 12 And .Range("L4") <= 19 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D9", ActiveSheet.Range("D9").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D9:D20"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                    Sheets(y).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D32", ActiveSheet.Range("D32").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D32:D43"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                End If

                'Select Copy data for Specials
                Sheets(y).Select
                If .Range("L50") = 0 Then
                    'No entries on this sheet
                    c = 0
                ElseIf .Range("L50") > 0 And .Range("L50") <= 12 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D55", ActiveSheet.Range("D55").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D55:D66"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                            Sheets(y).Select
                ElseIf .Range("L50") > 12 And .Range("L50") <= 19 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D55", ActiveSheet.Range("D55").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D55:D66"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                            Sheets(y).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D78", ActiveSheet.Range("D78").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D78:D89"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                End If

                'Select Copy data for Veterans
                Sheets(y).Select
                If .Range("L96") = 0 Then
                'No entries in Veterans
                a = a
                ElseIf .Range("L96") > 0 And .Range("L96") <= 12 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D101", ActiveSheet.Range("D101").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    d = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D101:D112"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + d
                ElseIf .Range("L96") > 12 Then
                MsgBox "Houston we have a problem! More than 12 in Veterans requires another sheet."
                Stop
                Else:
                a = a
                End If
            End With
            GoTo End_Loop

Copy_Wh:

            Sheets(y).Select
            With ActiveSheet
                If .Range("L4") = 0 Then
                    'No entries in Open
                    b = 0
                ElseIf .Range("L4") > 0 And .Range("L4") <= 12 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D9", ActiveSheet.Range("D9").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D9:D20"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                            Sheets(y).Select
                ElseIf .Range("L4") > 12 And .Range("L4") <= 24 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D9", ActiveSheet.Range("D9").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D9:D20"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                    Sheets(y).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D32", ActiveSheet.Range("D32").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D32:D43"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                ElseIf .Range("L4") > 24 And .Range("L4") <= 29 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D9", ActiveSheet.Range("D9").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D9:D20"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                    Sheets(y).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D32", ActiveSheet.Range("D32").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D32:D43"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                    Sheets(y).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D55", ActiveSheet.Range("D55").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D55:D66"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + b
                End If

                'Select Copy data for Specials
                Sheets(y).Select
                If .Range("L73") = 0 Then
                    'No entries on this sheet
                    c = 0
                ElseIf .Range("L73") > 0 And .Range("L73") <= 12 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D78", ActiveSheet.Range("D78").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D78:D89"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                            Sheets(y).Select
                ElseIf .Range("L73") > 12 And .Range("L73") <= 19 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D78", ActiveSheet.Range("D78").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D78:D89"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                            Sheets(y).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D101", ActiveSheet.Range("D101").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D101:D112"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                            Sheets(y).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D124", ActiveSheet.Range("D124").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    c = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D124:D135"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + c
                End If

                'Select Copy data for Veterans
                Sheets(y).Select
                If .Range("L142") = 0 Then
                'No entries in Veterans
                a = a
                ElseIf .Range("L142") > 0 And .Range("L142") <= 12 Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("D147", ActiveSheet.Range("D147").End(xlDown)).Copy
                    d = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D147:D158"))
                        Sheets("ASFA Certs_RollCall").Activate
                            With ActiveSheet
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).Select
                                .Range("K3").Offset(a, e).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                                :=False, Transpose:=False
                            End With
                            a = a + d
                ElseIf .Range("L142") > 12 Then
                MsgBox "Houston we have a problem! More than 12 in Veterans requires another sheet."
                Stop
                Else:
                a = a
                End If
            End With
            GoTo End_Loop
End_Loop:
    x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've put into this, but it's too much for me to read. Is the goal just to re-format some data that you've acquired, or is this 30-rows-at-a-time process something that will be ongoing?

Comment: Thats a lot of code! Your end result, is it just a solid block of `registration numbers` 30 rows by as many columns required?

Comment: A piece of advice for you to consider for this and future projects: Break your Script in functional blocks and put those in separate `Sub`s and `Function`s with meaningful names. Especially considering your small amount of local variables it should be rather easy to break it up like that.

Comment: Doug, Nick and K_B: Sorry about all the code. I wasn't sure how much or little would be helpful :). Nick's response is closest to what I'm trying to accomplish with one exception - The columns are placed at specific places on the worksheet. I think the response Floris provided may help but in the meantime I think I've come up with an easier plan - that is to copy everything to cells I'm not using then paste 30 at a time to the specific areas of the sheet.

Comment: Also K_B thanks for the advice about breaking up the code.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other people who have commented, I am drowning a bit in the volume of code you wrote. I'm going to offer a short piece of code you might be able to use - it will need some adapting, but it might be helpful.

```
dim curRow, curCol
dim c as Cell

' loop around the regions you want to select (pick first cell, extend with .End(xlDown) )
' select the data you want to copy, then
For each c in Selection.Cells
    if curRow < 30 Then 
        curRow = curRow+1 
    Else
        curRow = 1
        curCol = curCol + 1
    End If
    [A1].offset(curRow, curCol).Value = c
Next c

' repeat for next region... this can be a loop too
```

As you can see, this uses the `curRow` and `curCol` variables to keep track of where the data is going to be copied. By considering the cells one at a time we can just keep updating the target address. Obviously you need to adjust the offset (instead of [A1] which is shorthand for Range("A1"), use whatever the correct starting address is).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Floris, this will definitely help!